# Problem in concatenating 3 strings in bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to concatenate 3 strings in a bash script file.

```
#!/bin/sh
v1="aaaaaa"
v2="bbbb"$v1
v3=$v2"cc"
echo $v2
echo $v3
```

Result:

```
bbbbaaaaaa
ccbbaaaaaa
```

As you can see, 3rd string appears at the beginning and replace some characters of the main string. 
What can I do for this problem?

Comment: Everything works as expected. I see no problem.

Comment: The output of `echo $v2` is correct. The alleged output of `echo $v3` is not even remotely compatible with that script.

Comment: Did you create the script in a Windows or Mac text editor? Sometimes this kind of thing happens if the lines have `\r` line endings. You can [edit] your question to add the output of `cat -net yourfile`. BTW unless you have modified the default symlink for `/bin/sh`, you actually have written a `dash` script not a `bash` script.

Comment: The logic is correct. The result you put is incorrect. type again in bash

Comment: I've created the script by vi editor. and  `/bin/sh` is just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The script has  been edited in windows format (with a CRLF end of line by the editor). Apart the fact that's a `/bin/sh` and not `/bin/bash`, you can use

```
echo -E $v3
```

in order to suppress the \r (carriage return), as per any other escape char.

Comment: I make this bash script file with vi editor

Comment: vi under linux end the line only with 0A (LF). So the issue will not apply. Have you changed something in configuration, or using vi from cygwin? Or copy/pasted?